# Using date parameter in strftime function inside prepared SQLite query in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I have this issue, I'm executing a query where I'm trying to pass date from GET parameter into a function call:

```sql
SELECT ... WHERE ... strftime('%s', ?)
```

if I hardcode "2021-10-1" it works, but if I use a parameter, my query returns an empty array.

My whole code looks like this:

```php
<?php
$db = new PDO('sqlite:price.db');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

function query($query, $data = null) {
    global $db;
    if ($data == null) {
        $res = $db->query($query);
    } else {
        $res = $db->prepare($query);
        if ($res) {
            if (!$res->execute($data)) {
                throw Exception("execute query failed");
            }
        } else {
            throw Exception("wrong query");
        }
    }
    if ($res) {
        if (preg_match("/^\s*INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE|ALTER|CREATE|DROP/i", $query)) {
            return $res->rowCount();
        } else {
            return $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Coudn't open file");
    }
}

function data($date, $name) {
    $query = "SELECT
             price,
             datetime(time.time, 'unixepoch', 'utc') as date, 
             shop.name
           FROM
             price
           LEFT JOIN product on price.product = product.id
           LEFT JOIN shop on shop.id = price.shop
           LEFT JOIN time on price.time = time.id
           WHERE product.name = ? and time.time > strftime('%s', ?)
           ORDER BY time.time";
    return query($query, array($name, $date));
}

if (!isset($_GET['type'])) {
    header('cotent-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(data($_GET['date'], $_GET['name']));
}



?>
```

What is the best way (or simplest) to execute a query like this?

Comment: Use YYYY-MM-DD format for the dates with SQLite. Pass '2021-10-01'

Comment: @forpas Thanks, it works. You can add this as an answer and I will update the title since it's related to the formatting of dates.

Comment: Fine if it works. There is no need for an answer. This has been asked and answered several times in SO.